# Is there something like NSFileManager.enumeratorAtPath that takes a list of directories to exclude from recursion?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Is there something like `NSFileManager.enumeratorAtPath(path)` available that can recursively list files inside `path`, but not to descend into folders with certain names (e.g. `foo` or `*.-files`?

In Java, for example, there's a method named [`walkFileTree(path, fileVisitor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-), and when it reaches a directory, the [fileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) can decide whether the contents of that directory should be visited too or not:

```
FileVisitor fileVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    if (dir.toString().contains("foo")) {
      return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
    }

    // do something with dir and continue walking the directory

    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    // do something with file and continue, etc.
    return CONTINUE;
  }
};

Files.wakFileTree(startingPoint, fileVisitor);
```

Is there something similar to this available in Cocoa/Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use [`skipDescendants`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDirectoryEnumerator/skipDescendants).

EDIT: Yes. That's it.